# Disappearing content in HTML Layout of Coldfusion Datagrid

Tags: html, css, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm having an issue with my CFM page layout. I'm laying out a CFM page with 3 components in the top level div and they are displaying nicely. 
However when I set a new div below it and place a Coldfusion datagrid in a coldfusion form tag then test it, my top element disappears. When I remove the < cfform > block from my div it goes back to normal and displays fine with just texted wrapped in a . Help resolving this formatting issue would be greatly appreciated. I've attached images to show the issue.

[image: With just text in the second div section]
[image: This is after I put my < cfform > block in the second div section]

```
<div id="entire-page-div" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
         <div id="left_module" style="position: relative; width: 33%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
         <label for="reportsList">Available Employees:</label>               <!---This is the available employees list. Returns employees not assigned to a report--->
         <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%"><!---Form Initialization--->
         <cfselect name="employee" query="getAvailableEmployees"             <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Available Employee  query --->
          value="Full_Name" display="Full_Name" required="yes" size="10">    <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Available Employee  query --->
         </cfselect>
         </cfform>
            </div>

           <!---     ---->
           <!---     ---->
           <!---     ---->

            <div id="center_div" style="position: relative; width: 34%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <!---Assigned Employees Module--->
       <label for="reportsList">Assigned Employees:</label>
       <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">  <!---Assigned Employee Form Initialization--->
        <cfselect name="employee" query="getAssignedEmployees"               <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Employee Assignment query --->
        value="Full_Name" display="Full_Name" required="yes" size="10">      <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Employee Assignment query --->
        </cfselect>
        </cfform>
            </div>

          <!---     ---->
          <!---     ---->
          <!---     ---->

            <div id="right_div" style="position: relative; width: 33%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <!---Report List Module --->
                 <label for="reportsList">Reports List:</label>
                <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">
                <cfselect name="employee" query="getReports" 
                value="Report_Name" display="Report_Name" required="yes" size="10">
                </cfselect>
                </cfform>
            </div>

        </div>

     **Code In Question**
    <!---DataGrid Control Pane--->
  <div id="right_div" style="position: relative; width: 100%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
    <cflayout type="tab" tabheight="100" name="controlTabs" width="900" height="600">               <!---Tabbed layout controller for all tabbed layout components --->
    <cflayoutarea name="tab1" title="Employee Report Assignments" align="center"> 
     <cfform height="600" width="900">
    <cfgrid  
        name="AssignedReports" 
        align="Top" 
        autoWidth="yes" 
        bgColor="FFF"
        colHeaderBold="yes" 
        format="html"
        gridDataAlign="left" 
        gridLines="yes" 
        query="qEmployeeAssignments" 
        sort="yes" 
        stripeRowColor="FC6" 
        stripeRows="yes"
        width="900" height="500"> 

        <cfgridcolumn name="Full_Name" header="Employee Name" display="yes" width="300" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="reportName" header="Report Name" hrefKey="videogameid" target="_blank" width="300" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="reportDescrip" header="Report Description" dataalign="center" type="date" width="300" />       
    </cfgrid>
</cfform>
 </cflayoutarea> 
 </cflayout>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the kind of stuff that happens when you use the cf ui tags. They embed javascript into your pages that you have no control over. I'm guessing the javascript from the cfform is interfering with the javascript from the cfgrid. That being said it doesn't look like you are using anything special on that cfform tag. Can you just use a regular HTML form tag instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response. You gave me an idea which ended up working. Your idea of using a regular html form tag wouldn't be permitted with < cfgrid >. But I flipped my divs, added a second set of selection boxes at the top and was then able to delete the selection boxes at the bottom and it kept the layout just right. Odd bugginess to say the least.

Comment: _Odd bugginess to say the least_ - yes it is and this is typical when using the built-in cf ui tags. You will have more control and greater functionality if you use standard javascript libraries instead. Glad you got this working. Go ahead and post your solution as an answer to your own question. It is okay to do that here. That way others that come across this in the future will see your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: I was able to fix this issue by the following:

1. Place my CF layout block at the top of my page,
2. Copy my div with the 3 form elements and put it back at the top. Save it.
3. Delete the duplic div block at the botton.

Code:

```
<!---This begins the visual component layout--->
     <div id="entire-page-div" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
     <div id="left_module" style="position: relative; width: 33%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <label for="reportsList">Available Employees:</label>                 <!---This is the available employees list. Returns employees not assigned to a report--->
     <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">  <!---Form Initialization--->
     <cfselect name="employee" query="getAvailableEmployees"               <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Available Employee  query --->
     value="Full_Name" display="Full_Name" required="yes" size="10">       <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Available Employee  query --->
     </cfselect>
     </cfform>
     </div>

           <!---     ---->
           <!---     ---->
           <!---     ---->

     <div id="center_div" style="position: relative; width: 34%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <!---Assigned Employees Module--->
     <label for="reportsList">Assigned Employees:</label>
     <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">    <!---Assigned Employee Form Initialization--->
     <cfselect name="employee" query="getAssignedEmployees"                  <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Employee Assignment query --->
     value="Full_Name" display="Full_Name" required="yes" size="10">         <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Employee Assignment query --->
     </cfselect>
     </cfform>
     </div>

          <!---     ---->
          <!---     ---->
          <!---     ---->

     <div id="right_div" style="position: relative; width: 33%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <!---Report List Module --->                                           
     <label for="reportsList">Reports List:</label>
     <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">   <!---Report List Form Initialization--->
     <cfselect name="employee" query="getReports"                           <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Get Report query--->
     value="Report_Name" display="Report_Name" required="yes" size="10">    <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Get Report query--->
     </cfselect>
     </cfform>
     </div>            
     </div>
    <br/>
        <br/>
         <br/>
        <br/>



<!---Tabbed layout controller for all tabbed layout components ---> 
<cflayout type="tab" tabheight="100" name="mytabs">                         <!---Initialization for tab navigation layout--->
<cflayoutarea title="Employee Perspective" name="t1">                       <!---First Tab navigation pane initialization--->
<cfform>                                                                    <!---CF form initialization --->
    <cfgrid                                                                 <!---CF datagrid initialization--->
        name="AssignedEmployees"                                            <!--- -------Attributes---------- --->
        align="Top"                                                         <!---            |               --->
        autoWidth="yes"                                                     <!---            |               --->
        bgColor="FFF"                                                       <!---            |               --->
        colHeaderBold="yes"                                                 <!---            |               --->
        format="html"                                                       <!---            |               --->
        gridDataAlign="left"                                                <!---            |               --->
        gridLines="yes"                                                     <!---            |               --->
        query="qEmployeeAssignments"                                        <!---            |               --->
        sort="yes"                                                          <!---            |               --->
        stripeRowColor="FC6"                                                <!---            |               --->   
        stripeRows="yes"                                                    <!---            |               --->
        width="900" height="500">                                           <!---    End of Attributes       --->

        <cfgridcolumn name="Full_Name" header="Employee Name"               <!---Datagrid column. Mapped to the First and Last Names in the query--->
        display="yes" width="300" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="reportName" header="Report Name"                <!---Datagrid column. Mapped to the First and Last Names in the query--->
        hrefKey="videogameid" target="_blank" width="300" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="reportDescrip" header="Report Description"      <!---Datagrid column. Mapped to the First and Last Names in the query--->
        dataalign="center" type="date" width="300" />       
    </cfgrid>
    </cfform>
     </cflayoutarea>
     <cflayoutarea title="Reporting Perspective" name="t2">                 <!---First Tab navigation pane initialization--->
<cfform>                                                                    <!---CF form initialization --->
    <cfgrid                                                                 <!---CF datagrid initialization--->
        name="ReportsToEmployees"                                           <!--- -------Attributes---------- --->
        align="Top"                                                         <!---            |               --->
        autoWidth="yes"                                                     <!---            |               --->
        bgColor="FFF"                                                       <!---            |               --->
        colHeaderBold="yes"                                                 <!---            |               --->
        format="html"                                                       <!---            |               --->
        gridDataAlign="left"                                                <!---            |               --->
        gridLines="yes"                                                     <!---            |               --->
        query="qEmployeeAssignments"                                        <!---            |               --->
        sort="yes"                                                          <!---            |               --->
        stripeRowColor="FC6"                                                <!---            |               --->   
        stripeRows="yes"                                                    <!---            |               --->
        width="900" height="500">                                           <!---    End of Attributes       --->

        <cfgridcolumn name="reportName" header="Report Name"                <!---Datagrid column. Mapped to the First and Last Names in the query--->
        hrefKey="videogameid" target="_blank" width="300" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="Full_Name" header="Employee Name"               <!---Datagrid column. Mapped to the First and Last Names in the query--->
        display="yes" width="300" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="reportDescrip" header="Report Description"      <!---Datagrid column. Mapped to the First and Last Names in the query--->
        dataalign="center" type="date" width="300" />       
    </cfgrid>
    </cfform>
     </cflayoutarea>
    </cflayout>
**Delete this block after saving, then save again. Layout then works**
 <!---This begins the visual component layout--->
     <div id="entire-page-div" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
     <div id="left_module" style="position: relative; width: 33%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <label for="reportsList">Available Employees:</label>                 <!---This is the available employees list. Returns employees not assigned to a report--->
     <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">  <!---Form Initialization--->
     <cfselect name="employee" query="getAvailableEmployees"               <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Available Employee  query --->
     value="Full_Name" display="Full_Name" required="yes" size="10">       <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Available Employee  query --->
     </cfselect>
     </cfform>
     </div>

           <!---     ---->
           <!---     ---->
           <!---     ---->

     <div id="center_div" style="position: relative; width: 34%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <!---Assigned Employees Module--->
     <label for="reportsList">Assigned Employees:</label>
     <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">    <!---Assigned Employee Form Initialization--->
     <cfselect name="employee" query="getAssignedEmployees"                  <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Employee Assignment query --->
     value="Full_Name" display="Full_Name" required="yes" size="10">         <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Employee Assignment query --->
     </cfselect>
     </cfform>
     </div>

          <!---     ---->
          <!---     ---->
          <!---     ---->

     <div id="right_div" style="position: relative; width: 33%; background-color:#CCC; float: left;">
     <!---Report List Module --->                                           
     <label for="reportsList">Reports List:</label>
     <cfform name="assignedEmployees" action="getReport.cfm" width="25%">   <!---Report List Form Initialization--->
     <cfselect name="employee" query="getReports"                           <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Get Report query--->
     value="Report_Name" display="Report_Name" required="yes" size="10">    <!---CFSELECT To populate form element from above Get Report query--->
     </cfselect>
     </cfform>
     </div>            
     </div>
```

It seems that putting the cf layout on top then "forcing it down with the original div block, and subsequently deleting the duplicate div block causes it to render properly.